# Rejected suggested edit doesn't appear in the page listing the suggested edits

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I rejected [a suggested edit on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13123) by improving it, and not selecting the "Suggested edit was helpful" checkbox.

[image: screenshot]

Notice the edit is shown only as rejected, when it normally would show the suggested edit as rejected from the Community user and edited from me.
The suggested edit doesn't appear on [the page listing the history of the suggested edits](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), though.

[image: screenshot]

Looking at [the revision page for that question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/69093/revisions), I don't see other edits, if not mine (which I did when improving/rejecting the suggested edit), and the first edit done from the OP.

[image: screenshot]

I am sure I clicked on the "improve" button, and not the "reject" one, to then click on the "history" tab, click on the post link shown there, and edit the post from the question page.
Even in that would be the case, the "history" tab should still show the rejected suggested edit.

What I was expecting to see is what I see for [this other suggested edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12803), which is shown in the "history" tab.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

#### Update

A similar case happened on this very site too. I did the same for [this suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13408). The difference is that the "history" tab shows the suggested edit as approved, when it was rejected.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Even in this case, the fact somebody else clicked on the "improve" button was not kept, as if the suggested edit was rejected, and then somebody edit the post.
Also the "history" tab forgot about the "improve" button being clicked; the difference is that the page about the suggested edit shows the suggested edit as rejected from the Community user.
This would explain why in the *Drupal Answers* case there is no track of the rejected edit in the "history" tab. In the second case there is track of the suggested edit since a user voted to approve it.

Comment: This is the behavior seen when there is a conflicting edit (not through the review page, but through the post itself) that overrides the suggested edit.  Are you sure you improved it and didn't go to the post itself to edit it?  If you did use /review then it looks like some sort of bug in which it didn't think you were using the review system.

Comment: Yes, I am sure I was reviewing the suggested edits, and I didn't reject the edit to then edit the post from the question page.

Comment: The edit was reviewed over an hour after it was first posted, making the possibility of a conflicting edit...slim, or of some sort of caching bug in which the "improve" option hit the real database before the original edit.

Comment: Just happened to me [here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21907), I noticed there is pending edit too late and kicked it out by mistake when doing my own edit. Then when I went to look for what I did I could find it only in Community User action list. :/